# vbscript SelectionNamespaces selectSingleNode error runtime error: Object required:

Tags: vbscript

I have the following xml in a file called response2.xml

```
    &lt;?xml version="1.0"?&gt;  
&lt;S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;  
&lt;S:Body&gt;&lt;ns2:commonServiceResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.mas.gepics.ab.com"&gt;  
&lt;return&gt;  
&lt;responseData&gt;&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;  
&lt;tnsa:GetABQData xmlns:tns="http://www.ab.com/ns/ABQ/ABQSchemaExtensions"
        xmlns:tnsa="http://www.ab.com/ns/ABQ/ABQMessageStandard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ab.com/ns/ABQ/ABQMessageStandard ABQSchemaHeaders.xsd"
        releaseID="string" versionID="string"&gt;  
        &lt;tnsa:ApplicationArea&gt;  
                &lt;tnsa:CreationDateTime&gt;2012-04-03T08:53:20&lt;/tnsa:CreationDateTime&gt;  
                &lt;tnsa:ABQHeader&gt;  
                        &lt;tnsa:VehicleAssemblyPlant&gt;CHW&lt;/tnsa:VehicleAssemblyPlant&gt;  
                        &lt;tnsa:Source&gt;GEPICS&lt;/tnsa:Source&gt;  
                        &lt;tnsa:Destination&gt;SEP&lt;/tnsa:Destination&gt;  
                        &lt;tnsa:TransactionCode&gt;  
                                &lt;tnsa:Transaction&gt;TACK&lt;/tnsa:Transaction&gt;  
                        &lt;/tnsa:TransactionCode&gt;  
                        &lt;tnsa:TriggerID&gt;0&lt;/tnsa:TriggerID&gt;  
                        &lt;tnsa:InputDevice&gt;MAS01&lt;/tnsa:InputDevice&gt;  
                        &lt;tnsa:OutputDevice&gt;MASOUT01&lt;/tnsa:OutputDevice&gt;  
                &lt;/tnsa:ABQHeader&gt;  
        &lt;/tnsa:ApplicationArea&gt;  
        &lt;tnsa:DataArea&gt;  
                &lt;tnsa:Get&gt;  
                        &lt;tnsa:Expression&gt;string&lt;/tnsa:Expression&gt;  
                &lt;/tnsa:Get&gt;  
                &lt;tnsa:ABQData releaseID="string"&gt;  
                        &lt;tnsa:ABQSpecific&gt;  
                                &lt;tnsa:Vehicle&gt;  
                                        &lt;tns:GEPICSTrgPrimaryKey&gt;101718664&lt;/tns:GEPICSTrgPrimaryKey&gt;  
                                        &lt;tns:GEPICSTrgSecondaryKey&gt;   &lt;/tns:GEPICSTrgSecondaryKey&gt;  
                                &lt;/tnsa:Vehicle&gt;  
                                &lt;tns:BroadCastData&gt;  
                                        &lt;tns:DataTagID&gt;231&lt;/tns:DataTagID&gt;  
                                        &lt;tns:DataLength&gt;34&lt;/tns:DataLength&gt;  
                                        &lt;tns:DataString&gt;ADDORDER1017186643G1SE51X3AS118601&lt;/tns:DataString&gt;  
                                &lt;/tns:BroadCastData&gt;  
                        &lt;/tnsa:ABQSpecific&gt;  
                &lt;/tnsa:ABQData&gt;  
        &lt;/tnsa:DataArea&gt;  
&lt;/tnsa:GetABQData&gt;  

&lt;/responseData&gt;  
&lt;success&gt;true&lt;/success&gt;  
&lt;/return&gt;  
&lt;/ns2:commonServiceResponse&gt;  
&lt;/S:Body&gt;  
&lt;/S:Envelope&gt;
```

I have the following vbscript called 5.vbs to read a node from the file

```
Set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.4.0")   
oXMLDoc.async = False   
oXMLDoc.load ("response2.xml")   
oXMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"   
oXMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:S='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ns2='http://webservice.mas.gepics.ab.com' xmlns:tnsa='http://www.ab.com/ns/ABQ/ABQMessageStandard'"  
WScript.Echo oXMLDoc.selectSingleNode("//S:Envelope//S:Body//ns2:commonServiceResponse//return//responseData").text
```

I execute  the command cscript 5.vbs and I get the following error
runtime error: Object required: 'oXMLDoc.selectSingleNode(...)'

no matter what I do I cannot select any nodes in the tnsa:GetABQData tree.

Any suggestions
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not obvious, but you don't have XML there. That is HTML encoded XML. You need to decode it if you expect to parse it with the XML parser. You can use this function to decode it first:

http://psacake.com/web/func/htmldecode_function.htm

```
Private Function HTMLDecode(byVal encodedstring)
    Dim tmp, i
    tmp = encodedstring
    tmp = Replace( tmp, "&quot;", chr(34) )
    tmp = Replace( tmp, "&lt;"  , chr(60) )
    tmp = Replace( tmp, "&gt;"  , chr(62) )
    tmp = Replace( tmp, "&amp;" , chr(38) )
    tmp = Replace( tmp, "&nbsp;", chr(32) )
    For i = 1 to 255
        tmp = Replace( tmp, "&#" & i & ";", chr( i ) )
     Next
    HTMLDecode = tmp
End Function
```